# How to add <div class="row"> every 2 elements while looping in Vue.JS template?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, templates, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I got an array of images's URL of variable length in my model.
I'd like to show on my page 2 images per row, and get a result like this:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <img ... />
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <img ... />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <img ... />
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <img ... />
  </div>
</div>
...
```

But I just don't figure out **how to conditionnaly add the opening and closing tags of `row`**.

This is what I tried but it doesn't work:
*I'm using [boostrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org), so  `b-container`, `b-row` and `b-col` are basically `<div class="container">,` and `<div class="col">`.*

```html
<b-container>
  <template v-for="(url, index) in urls">
    <template v-if="index % 2 == 0">
      <b-row :key="index">
    </template>
    <b-col :key="index">
      <p>{{ index }}</p>
      <b-img
        :src="url"
        alt="charts"
        fluid
      ></b-img>
    </b-col>
    <template v-if="index % 2 == 0">
      </b-row>
    </template>
  </template>
</b-container>
```

And the error:

```
 Errors compiling template:

  tag <b-row> has no matching end tag.

  40 |      <template v-for="(url, index) in urls">
  41 |        <template v-if="index % 2 == 0">
  42 |          <b-row :key="index">
     |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  43 |        </template>
  44 |        <b-col :key="index">
```

Comment: replace `<b-col :key="index">` by `<b-col v-bind:key="index">` ? or replace `<template v-for="(url, index) in urls">` by `<template v-for="(url, index) in urls" :key="index">` according to vueJS [documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Component).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would restructure your image array using a computed property that returns an array chunked into groups of two images.  You could even conditionally change the chunk size to increase or decrease the number of images in a row.

```
computed: {
   makeRows(){
     let row = [];
     let i,l, chunkSize = this.rowSize; 

     for (i=0,l=this.images.length; i<l; i+=chunkSize) {
       row.push(this.images.slice(i,i+chunkSize));

     }
     return row;
     }
  }
```

Here is a working example using an array.  https://jsfiddle.net/skribe/0fvj5643/7/

Answer (score -1):

I would do something like this:

```
 <template>
        <div v-for="url in urls">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <p>test</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <p>test</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</template>
```

Try it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-vue-sandbox-mpt2b

Comment: You misunderstood the question

Answer (score -1):

It's saying that your opening/closing tags don't match up. In your code:

```
<b-container>
  <template v-for="(url, index) in urls">
    <template v-if="index % 2 == 0">
      <b-row :key="index">
    </template>
    <b-col :key="index">
      <p>{{ index }}</p>
      <b-img
        :src="url"
        alt="charts"
        fluid
      ></b-img>
    </b-col>
    <template v-if="index % 2 == 0">
      </b-row>
    </template>
  </template>
</b-container>
```

You have `<b-row :key="index">`, which isn't closed by anything, and `</b-row>`, which isn't opened by anything. You can't do this. Since your `<template v-if="...">` tags check for the same thing, it'd probably be fine to do something like:

```
<b-container>
  <template v-for="(url, index) in urls">
    <template v-if="index % 2 == 0">
      <b-row :key="index">
        <b-col :key="index">
          <p>{{ index }}</p>
          <b-img
            :src="url"
            alt="charts"
            fluid
          ></b-img>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </template>
  </template>
</b-container>
```

I have no experience with vue-bootstrap so I don't know if this will raise any other issues, but this should fix the error currently being thrown.

Comment: This will display every other image, not  2 images side by side

Comment: I left the `<template v-if="index % 2 == 0">` stuff in from your question; I was addressing your error message. Honestly, I'd use custom CSS with flexbox/grid for this kind of thing personally, but if you're intent on using bootstrap then skribe's answer will solve your problem.